# Express.js return 404 not found to script tag only on production server

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, mime-types, helmet.js

Locally (Mac) on the computer (develop environment) all works fine when I make `curl` request to static, server response is 200, but if I'm running the same code on the server, and request to static the response is 404, for all other static like image, html files express responses 200.

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var sassMiddleware = require("node-sass-middleware");
var helmet = require("helmet");

var app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    indentedSyntax: false, // true = .sass and false = .scss
    outputStyle: "compressed",
    force: true,
    sourceMap: false
}));

app.disable("x-powered-by");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/index.html"));
});


module.exports = app;
```

Project tree is

```
   - app
    |- public
       |- assets (js files here)
       |- images
       |- stylesheets
       |- index.html
    |- node_modules
    |- bin
       | - www
    |- app.js
    |- package.json
    |- .gitignore
```

Response instance of `/` route

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Jan 2018 11:02:05 GMT
ETag: W/"1ac9-1611d8844f1"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 6857
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2018 11:45:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response instance of `/images/logo.png` route

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Jan 2018 06:25:07 GMT
ETag: W/"749-1611c8ab42f"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 1865
Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2018 11:46:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response instance of `/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` route which returns 404 Not Found

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 172
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2018 11:47:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: How did you deployed your application direct deployment or reverse proxy

Comment: Tried with reverse proxy (nginx) and without reverse proxy